# Memory leak in Flex application

Tags: apache-flex, memory-leaks, blazeds

I'm facing with a memory leak in my Flex application. 
The Flex application is part of a big web application (with all kinds of technologies inside).

The memory leak occurs when the Flex app invokes a refresh polling from the server every 5 sec.

**The facts are:**

- I'm using **AMFChannel** to make the connection. Polling is false. Each refresh creates new **AMFChannel** instance.
- Server side is **BlazeDS**, running as a servlet inside my web application.
- The memory leak occurs on **IE** and **FireFox**. It not occurs at all on **Chrome**.
- Over one night the IE memory increase in hundreds of MBs and eventually is crashing.
- In the Flex, the memory do increase but much slower. Over night it
  will increase in 30MB.
- Using the Flex profiler I saw that the increased memory is related to
  the **AMFChannels**.
- I tried to set **AMFChannel requestTimeout** to 60 sec. It did nothing.
- I tried to set **BlazeDS connect-timeout-seconds** to 60 sec. Nothing changed. But I'm not sure I did it correctly.

**My conclusions till now are:**

- The AMFChannel is actually gets a connections from the browser. In Flex the AMFChannel consuming small piece of memory, while in the browser it consume much more. This explain the different in the memory consuming between the Flex app and the IE.
- Somehow, the AMFChannel is not shutdown and not garbage collected.

**My requests:**

- Is my conclusions are right?
- How to make sure the AMFChannel is shutdown and cleaned up?
- Is the connection instance on the client is controlled by the BlazeDS (on the server side)?
- Any other clue to help me continue investigating this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We also have the same problem. The JVM goes out of memory every 24 - 50hrs. I have documented a working fix for the problem on the JVM side.

[Fixing blazeds memory leak](http://in-finite.me/fixing-blazeds-polling-amf-memory-leak/)

Answer (score 0):

Like all objects, at some point pointers need to be declared null to make it eligible for GC. With the AMFChannel object, your best method to this is to setup listeners for both the `channelDisconnect` and the `channelFault` events. Provided you have a class member reference to the instance, from either of these event handlers, you declare it null.

To determine if you should call disconnect from the client side, you can look at the properties of: shouldBeConnected and connected.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. If the AMFChannel is not free in Flex, does it cause to the connection object on the IE to stay up?

Comment: I added manually disconnect call to each RemoteObject that is live more then 1 minute. It looks like the Flex memory is stable, but the IE memory continue to grow.